# AddThis and Google Page Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, micro-optimization, addthis

No matter how I try to load AddThis (using Google +1, Facebook Send and Like, and Twitter buttons as default), [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) still warns about:

- Leverage browser caching
- Defer parsing of Javascript

In each of these items, .html and .js references to AddThis, Facebook, Google +1, Twitter, and static.ak.fbcdn.net are referenced. In fact, if you run Google Page Speed on this page: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api-#rendering-js, you will see exactly what I'm talking about. The first two items, both with orange severity icons (at least for me), are exactly what I mentioned above.

I've tried adding the script tag to the head of my page using defer (for IE) and async (for FF and Chrome) with no luck:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=myUserId" defer="defer" async="async"></script>
```

I've tried using $.getScript():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript('http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#async=1#username=myUserId', function(data, textStatus) {
        addthis.init();
    });
});
```

And I also tried turning the ajax cache on:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#async=1#username=myUserId', function(data, textStatus) {
        addthis.init();
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
});
```

Is there any way I can cache, and also defer the loading of AddThis and it's external references?

Comment: you get this warning on Low priority - correct ?

Comment: I re-ran it and got Medium for Defer parsing of JavaScript, low for Leverage browser caching. On my website, it's the opposite. Regardless, I understand that it's not really hindering performance, but I still want to fix it if I can. I'm extremely OCD about this stuff.

Comment: You do not have actually to fix something this is what I say about. You can how ever make a trick, you can load the addthis only when you needed, but is not so easy. You can make a button that looks like addthis have been loaded, but you can load it only when the user moves over it... is not so simple. (not load it on ready - but load it only if user needed it, click on it, etc)

Answer (score 0):

### Leverage browser caching

Well this is just a proposal to set more time cache of some pages. On my pages I get this two warning - both from google script :). Is not so important because this javascript all ready have a good time cache for javascript.

```
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js (60 minutes)
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js (2 hours)
```

### Defer parsing of Javascript

Well, this is an automatic program that try to understand if the page is slow and suggest some thinks to improve it. At this point is not accurate.

I just run it on known page that work find and full of cache and other tricks, and get the same messages.

Is like just a suggestion and not actually can know if this javascript really do all ready what he say - at least for the moment. For example in my test page I load a javascript at the end of the page and I get this message again. If you know that you load the javascript at the correct timing with the correct flags, do not worry about this messaage.

Check the report for this page :

https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/#url=http_3A_2F_2Fstackoverflow.com_2Fquestions_2F9739031_2Faddthis-and-google-page-speed&mobile=false&rule=LeverageBrowserCaching

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8" src="/js/addthis.js#async=1"</script>
```

This has been resolved in our site. http://www.nbhuntop.com
You may try copy the addthis code first. and quote as `src="/js/addthis.js#async=1"`